# Asking an option to hamburger menu

Tags: hamburger

In the recent years we can see that hamburger menus have gained higher user experiences. But these days we can see that hamburger menus are getting popular even in big screen devices. I have been searching and researching an option to hamburger menu. Can any one suggest me an option to the hamburger?

Comment: You mean like an alternative for the hamburger menu? Like the three dots Microsoft uses? *...*

Comment: like so but..in exact i meant if hamburger extincts what will be the next option to hamburger

Comment: @BennySkogberg [So if that other thing is a ‘hamburger’ menu, what are we calling this thing? Meatballs?](https://twitter.com/inkblurt/status/560126060109393920)

Comment: @RogerAttrill way too small for meatballs. I was thinking a peas menu icon ^^

Answer (score 4):

While I was initially tempted to just say that the word 'MENU' should stand the test of time, the trouble is I fear that the design as a whole might not.

The hamburger menu isn't always the best option to hide a menu away because it does exactly that - **it hides the menu**!

This [case study from Redbooth](https://redbooth.com/blog/hamburger-menu-iphone-app) details how they got rid of the generic hamburger menu, replacing it with easy access to main features, and the ubiquitous settings option.

So - the alternative option to the hamburger - [as I have said before](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/60709/6046) - is to take a good look at the navigational structure and wayfinding at the higher level.

---

Never say never - [for some, the hamburger menu may work](http://conversionxl.com/testing-hamburger-icon-revenue/#/)  - and as LukeW said:

> My biggest gripe with the "hamburger" menu isn't the icon, it's that it
>   has become a way to get all our old desktop menus on mobile.